# Returning multiple object types using tyeporm using an inner join(Node,js,typescript)

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Assume that I have two tables `user` and `userProfile`. When I join both the tables, I get something like this:

```
            {"first_name": "asda",
            "last_login_time": null,
            "last_name": "dasdasd",
            "p_birth_date": "",
            "p_city": "",
            "p_college_name": "",
            "p_college_year": ""
        }
```

instead of this i need result like this :-

```
  { "first_name": "asda",
        "last_login_time": null,
        "last_name": "dasdasd",
        "user_profile":{
          "p_birth_date": "",
          "p_city": "",
          "p_college_name": "",
          "p_college_year": ""
        }
    }
```

and I'm using MySQL. Is there any way in Typeorm or in MySQL raw query which returns this result?

This is the code which resulting the 1st example:-

```
let data = await slaveSchema.createQueryBuilder()

      .select("*")
      .from(a_users, "usr")
      .innerJoin(a_user_profiles, "usrPro", "usr.user_id = usrPro.profile_user_id")
      .where("usr.user_id =:id", { id: userId })
      .execute()
```

Comment: Please, post the code of both TypeORM entities and your query so we can have a more wide vision on what you have done.